# SQL Server - Troubleshooting

Tags: sql-server

**I IDENTIFIED THE ISSUE (MY OWN STUPIDITY) - SO I EDITED MY QUESTION TO BETTER REFLECT THE ANSWER**

---

.

I'm having some issues with a specific table on SQL Server. Are there any troubleshooting queries I can run to try and identify the problem.

---

Table storage properties:
**Data space**: 113MB
**Index space**: 306MB
**Row count**: 25000

SQL Server version:
`Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right there might be a number of issues, but there is a clever way to investigate.
I would suggest you to create few SQL Server Extended Events sessions to catch what is happening on your instance to have a solid base for your further investigation. XE are not as resource greedy as the profiler was so they **should** be fine to run till you find your bug. Once you have your basic data SO will be happy to help further :)

Ps. Please put the real timing you are interested in for the first session value in place of 10 sec I have done as an example.

```
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Query duration over 10 sec:
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Duration_Over_10_Seconds] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(SET collect_output_parameters=(1),collect_statement=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.is_system,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([duration]>(10000000)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Duration_Over_10_Seconds',max_file_size=(250),max_rollover_files=(3))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Blocking queries (above the 'blocked process threshold' sqrver config)
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Blocking] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.blocked_process_report
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Blocking',max_file_size=(250),max_rollover_files=(3))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Aplication Aborts  (time outs)
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE EVENT SESSION [TimeOuts] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(SET collect_output_parameters=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.is_system,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.plan_handle,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([result]=(2)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'TimeOuts',max_file_size=(250),max_rollover_files=(3))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Deadlocks:
--|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Deadlocks] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Deadlocks', max_file_size=(250), max_rollover_files=(3))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB, EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS, MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS, MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE, TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON, STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```